# Conditional Animation for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Trying to get conditional animation to work. This method works for just two classes (left and right) but gets weird with three classes.(sometimes it will fade, sometimes it will use left/right) It also gets unwieldy with more classes. Any tips?

I have whatever I want to animate (in this case it would be ng-view) with these classes already defined.

```
ng-class="{animateLeft: goingLeft, animateRight: goingRight, fadeIn: fading}"
```

I add these functions to ng-click() on my navigation buttons.

```
$scope.goRight = function(){
 $scope.goingRight = true;
 $scope.goingLeft  = false;
 $scope.fading     = false;
};

$scope.goLeft = function(){
 $scope.goingRight = false;
 $scope.goingLeft  = true;
 $scope.fading     = false;
};

$scope.fadeIn = function(){
 $scope.goingRight = false;
 $scope.goingLeft  = false;
 $scope.fading     = true;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was being weird. This method actually does work. You just need to understand how angular animates things step by step.

To animate something in angular you assign it 4 CSS classes.

1)The state it should start in when it ENTERS. (e.g. off to the side and invisible)

2)The state it should end in when it ENTERS. (e.g. going to the middle and visible)

3)The state it should start in when it EXITS. (e.g. start from the middle and visible)

4)The state it should end in when it EXITS. (e.g. go to the side and invisible)

This means that there are TWO objects on "stage" as the same time as the animation is occurring (one is leaving while the other is entering). When an object enters the stage, it's already programmed to leave in a certain way. When the other objects comes onto the stage, that objects leaves.

My problem was that I wanted my view to conditionally LEAVE as well as conditionally ENTER. I could call the ENTER animation properly but because the LEAVE conditional was already set BEFORE knowing how I'd call enter the way it leaves cannot be changed.

I changed my code so that the pages animate into the stage based on a condition (e.g. animate in from arrow direction you click) but made them fade to 0 on leave instead of leave in the opposite direction. Previously the animations were weird because I would click on RIGHT, the page would animate in from the right, but then when I wanted to fade to another page the previous page would leave to the LEFT which was confusing.

Just remember that the page your animating get both its enter AND leave classes set when you call it.